# Person cannot be converted to HashMap<String, Person>

Tags: java, hashmap

I think I understand what the error message means, that I have a Person, and am trying to convert it to HashMap< String, Person>, but that is not what the code says? I dont understand what I´m doing wrong. As I read the code, I see no problems..
I´ve been stuck at this for a while now.. If there´s something fundamental I´ve missed I´d love to hear it, because I just don´t get this error message

```
//Variable HashMap
public static HashMap<String, Person> personer = new HashMap<String, Person>();

//Method newPerson
public HashMap<String, Person> newPerson(String name) {
            Person person = new Person(name);
            return personer.put(name, person);
    }

//Method to read file
public void readFile(String filnavn) throws Exception {
        String line;
        String current;

        File file = new File(filnavn);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            line = in.nextLine();
            personer.put(newPerson(line));
        }
    }
```

At return personer.put(name, person); I get the error saying incompatible types: Person cannot be converted to HashMap< String, Person >;

I also get an error at personer.put(newPerson(line)); saying no suitable method found, but I think the two errors are correlated?

Comment: What do you think the type of the expression `personer.put(name, person)` is? And are you sure the result of the `put` method is what you want to return?

Comment: And no, the second error has nothing to do with the first - you're trying to add just a value instead of a key and a value. It's not clear why you're adding to the map in both methods though...

Comment: Probably not HashMap <String, Person>. So the method should be:
public Person newPerson() and not
public HashMap< String, Person > () ?

Comment: Like what @JonSkeet said, have a look at how you call [map.put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) and the value is returned from that. Trying to understand what the errors mean and why will give you a clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: Because you are trying to add returned HashMap into to personer HashMap. Just call newPerson(line) method.

Comment: Thank you very much by the way Jon! I understood the second error message, and the abundancy of personer.put in readFile()
I think it just might work now:)

Answer (score 2):

You have some logical problem in your code, the `personer.put(name, person)` return a `Person` not a `HashMap<String, Person>` 
In your `readFile` you opened a file two times

```
    File file = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filnavn)); // new File(filnavn), you didn't use the file !
```

I think you want to read the file which contain persons name in each line. 
Here's how you could

```
//Method to read file
public void readFile(String filnavn) throws Exception {
    String line;
    String current; // you didn't use this variable !

    File file = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        personer.put(line,new Person(line)); // you don't need the newPerson(String name) method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the return here:

```
public HashMap<String, Person> newPerson(String name) {
    Person person = new Person(name);
    return personer.put(name, person);
}
```

This doesn't work as personer.put returns a Person and not a Map so you need to either make the method return a Person, or return the personer map

So, change it to this to return the map:

```
public HashMap<String, Person> newPerson(String name) {
    Person person = new Person(name);
    personer.put(name, person);
    return personer;
}
```

This way the method returns the Map as the method definition requires.

As for the construtor you are using the method you created which returns a Map, instead of the class construtor which should be:

```
new Person("name");
```

So it would have to be like this assuming there's a construtor which takes a String in the Person class:

```
public void readFile(String filnavn) throws Exception {
    String line;
    String current;

    File file = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        personer.put(new Person(line));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the map, then return the map.  Instead you are returning the result of the map put operation which is not a map itself.